# Correções no Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, fullcalendar

tô tentando ajustar a posição de exibição do conteúdo dentro do primeiro , aquele que mostra o Mês/Dia. Gostaria que fosse exibido como:

*Dia/Mês, **Ex: 23/08.***

Procurei, porém minha falta de "habilidade" com o Js está me atrapalhando um pouco, rs.

Ah é dentro da aba "Week".

Obrigado desde já!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está se referindo a esse: [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar).
Basta configurar o formato da data na propriedade [`columnFormat`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/columnFormat/), como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'ddd', // Mon
            week: 'ddd D/M', // Mon 18/8
            day: 'dddd' // Monday
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2014-08-18'
    });
});
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/Lu90x5mz/)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado Jader!